# ckan datastore set permission error

Tags: postgresql, datastore, ckan

I successfully installed CKAN2.2 from source to Ubuntu 12.04. Then continued to "Setting up the DataStore". An error occurs while setting the datastore permissions with the command below. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed to fix it?

Command:

> (default)user@myubuntu:/etc/ckan/default$ paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions |
>   sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1

Error:

> 2014-07-10 16:07:05,390 WARNI [ckanext.datastore.plugin] Omitting permission checks because you are running paster commands.
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Perform"
>   LINE 1: Perform commands to set up the datastore.
>           ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using CKAN 2.2, but following the docs from the development version. See the 2.2 docs: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/datastore.html#set-permissions

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the sql script manually. i had the same issue and THIS solved my problem. Also, this happens (in my case) when using Postgres 9.0... also you have to comment the datastore.read entry in the config file

hope to have helped

Answer (score 0):

got same error when I installed from package as the doc by following two commands.
`$ sudo ckan datastore set-permissions | sudo -u postgres psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1`
`$ sudo ckan datastore set-permissions`
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "Perform"`
and finally successful by following command.
`$ sudo ckan datastore set-permissions postgres`
`Set permissions for read-only user: SUCCESS`